# Windows 10 update: 2004 first, or 20H2 directly?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit 1909. A few months back, I was informed that the feature update 2004 was ready to download, but as I read it was troublesome for some people, I put off upgrading for quite a while. Recently, the 2004 upgrade disappeared from Windows Update, replaced by upgrade 20H2. I checked, and I'm still running 1909. Sooner or later I guess I'll have to upgrade, so my question is:

- Is it alright to upgrade straight from 1909 to 20H2?

I read [here](https://pureinfotech.com/should-install-windows-10-20h2-now/) that it might require basically a full reinstall and I'm really not up for that.

- Would upgrading to 2004 first spare me the trouble?
- Is there any way to do that through Windows Update without
  downloading a ISO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do that through Windows Update without downloading a ISO?

You can upgrade to the current feature update by using the [Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3159635/windows-10-update-assistant).  Since the upgrade assistant and the media creation tool will only download the current feature update the only way to download and upgrade to 2004 would be through the ISO.

> Sooner or later I guess I'll have to upgrade, so my question is: is it alright to upgrade straight from 1909 to 20H2?

Windows will automatically upgrade to the current feature update approximately 6 months from now.  That is approximately when support for 1909 will end.  Support for 1903 expires on December 3rd 2020.

> If 20H2 is a service update to 2004, but I'm still running 1909, why can't I see 2004 anymore in my Windows Update?

20H2 is still a feature update, however, had you installed 2004 you could enable all its features with a enablement package.

[Feature Update through Windows 10, version 20H2 Enablement Package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4562830/feature-update)

> is it alright to upgrade straight from 1909 to 20H2

You wouldn’t be offered 20H2 through Windows Update if your machine wasn’t supported.  Any issues Microsoft has identified has a reason to block the upgrade is listed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-20h2).  I encourage you to see if any of those issues are applicable to your machine.

> Would upgrading to 2004 first spare me the trouble?

Upgrading to 2004 is unnecessary since 20H2 has been released. If you were to upgrade to 2004, you would still be upgraded to 20H2 through that enablement package, which would be installed automatically through Windows Update the next time Windows performed an update.

**20H2 literally is a service update to 2004.** 1909 is also considered a service update to 1903 which has its own enablement package.